# How to simulate pressing a few keys on the keyboard, including special?

Tags: python, python-3.x, win32com

Installed the `win32com module.client` it is possible to do simulated keystrokes (`Ctrl + C`):

```
shell = win32com.client.Dispatch('WScript.Shell')
shell.SendKeys('^a^x')
```

However, in the process there was one very strange feature: all of these simulation pressing the run in background thread. In my case this is unacceptable. How to make the whole program waited until the simulated depression? Tried `threading` - turned, but the program is now running 3s 0.1 s, which is unacceptable.